# no suitable method found for addOnSuccessListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm a beginner in Android Studio. I get an error when I try to follow someone's code. My code is like this:

```
getReference.child("Owner").child(getUserID).child("Ternak").push()
                        .setValue(new LiveStockData(getNamaTernak, getNamaPeternak, getJenisTernak))
                        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                //Peristiwa ini terjadi saat user berhasil menyimpan datanya kedalam Database
                                namaTernak.setText("");
                                namaPeternak.setText("");
                                jenisTernak.setText("");
                                Toast.makeText(addDataActivity.this, "Data Tersimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

and then I got this error:

```
error: no suitable method found for addOnSuccessListener(<anonymous OnClickListener>,<anonymous OnSuccessListener<Void>>)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        ^
method Task.addOnSuccessListener(Executor,OnSuccessListener<? super Void>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Executor)
method Task.addOnSuccessListener(Activity,OnSuccessListener<? super Void>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Activity)
```

What should I do to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to provide context as the first parameter in `onSuccessListener`, so try like this:

```
getReference.child("Owner").child(getUserID).child("Ternak").push()
                        .setValue(new LiveStockData(getNamaTernak, getNamaPeternak, getJenisTernak))
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                                //Peristiwa ini terjadi saat user berhasil menyimpan datanya kedalam Database
                                namaTernak.setText("");
                                namaPeternak.setText("");
                                jenisTernak.setText("");
                                Toast.makeText(addDataActivity.this, "Data Tersimpan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

What I did is just changed this line:

```
.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener() {
```

to this line:

```
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
```

**EDIT:** According to this documentation, you don't need to provide `this` as the first parameter. So check this for anything related to Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

Also watch with those tutorials since Firebase changed over time, so some tutorials might be outdated. Check documentation for more knowledge and understanding of how it works: https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides